# Where to put test utils in Next.js projects?

Tags: typescript, next.js, jestjs

I have a pretty standard Next.js (12.x) React (18.x) project with Jest (28.x) for testing. My tests e.g. `__tests__/Product.test.tsx` will run just fine, but now I have some utils I'd like to reuse across tests and tried this:

`__tests__/util/my-test-helper.ts`

```
export function setupSomeThing() {
  return { foo: jest.fn() };
}
```

and then `import` that function in my tests. But the test runner complains with:

> ```
> FAIL  __tests__/util/my-test-helper.ts
>
> * Test suite failed to run
>   Your test suite must contain at least one test.
> ```

How can I prevent this issue? [The Next.js testing documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/testing) seems to have no instruction for this case.

What is the convention or solution (or workaround) for Next.js Jest tests?

Comment: Exclude the helpers from Jest's test match pattern?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sharing my current workaround, which is to put utils in:

```
__tests-utils__/my-test-helper.ts
```

As per the comments, perhaps a Jest test match pattern change would help, or perhaps a default exception already exists which could be used by convention. Regardless, above variant works too.

Answer (score 0):

Exclude files that do not end with test.ts(x) or test.js(x) in the Jest runner configuration.

```
// in your jest.config
testRegex: '.*\\.test\\.tsx?$'
```